Use OAuth2 Client Credential authentication in Azure Data Factory
I need to make a REST API call to fetch the data.
These are the details required for OAuth authentication type

I have the values for all the fields:
"OAuthConfig": {
        "Scope": "",
        "TokenEndpointHostname": "",
        "TenantId": "",
        "TokenEndpointResourcePath": "",
        "ClientId"
}

but I don't have the value for ClientSecret. Because it's a first party app it uses certificate and not key.
How do I make this work?


but I don't have the value for ClientSecret. Because it's a first party app it uses certificate and not key.

According to REST Connector document,it only supports below authenticate options:

Anonymous
Basic
AadServicePrincipal
OAuth2ClientCredential
ManagedServiceIdentity

It will not support for certificate authentication.
If you want to use certificate authentication you can use HTTP connector as shown below:

